Can I override a Cucumber step definition
I am working in a project where the Framework injected via Maven also contains some general stepDefinitions. Now I have one particular case, where I want to override one of these stepDefinitions. Is that at all possible? So in the Framework I have a step like.
@When("The user navigates to the basket")
public void theUserNavigatesToBasket {
    functionFactory.getHomepageFunctions().navigateToBasket();
}

I and want that in the features in my project I can use the very same expression "The user navigates to the basket", but redirect it to another method.

You can configure your glue path not to include specific packages, but you can't exclude classes or step definitions in packages that are included.

Thanks; I guess I have to go for different gherkin experessions then.
